# Changing eigenvalues of a Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix, with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ being the eigenvalues of $A$, $v_1$ being the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, and $d$ the column vector of dimension $n$, then are the eigenvalues of $A+v_1d^T$ equal to $\lambda_1+d^Tv_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $d$ is **the** column vector of dimension $n$?  Do you mean that $d$ is **a** column vector of dimension $n$?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This was my previous answer, it was wrong.  See the correct statement and proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565997/eigenvalue-alteration-counter-proof/1566060#1566060)

---

**Hint:** This is only generally true if we also know that $v_i$ is perpendicular to $d$ for $i=2,3,\dots,n$.  You should be able to construct a $2 \times 2$ counterexample.

Comment: Game on, let me try.

Comment: What is incorrect about this approach: A=$\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{matrix}$ and d=$\begin{matrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{matrix}$ ? d is parallel to $v_i$ for i=2 here