# Eigenvalue alteration counter-proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

If $A$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix, with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ being the eigenvalues of $A$, $v_1$ being the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, and $d$ the column vector of dimension $n$, then can anyone provide a counterexample to show the following statement is false: the eigenvalues of $A+v_1d^T$ are equal to $\lambda_1+d^Tv_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ ?

Any help or direction is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There are no $2 \times 2$ counterexamples, apparently

Comment: In the future, try to post questions from the [same account](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564747/changing-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

There are **no counterexamples,** this statement is apparently true (assuming that $u_1$ is a *unit* eigenvector).

One quick proof uses Schur triangularization: given $A$, find a change of basis $U$ such that $U^*AU$ is upper-triangular.  In particular,
$$
U^*AU = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 && *\\ &\ddots\\&&\lambda_n}
$$
Then, we find that
$$
U^*(A + u_1d^*)U = U^*AU + (U^*u_1)(U^*d)^* = U^*AU + e_1(U^*d)^*
$$
Let $w = U^*d$, we then have
$$
U^*(A + u_1d^*)U= 
\pmatrix{\lambda_1 + w_1 &&& *\\&\lambda_2 \\&&\ddots\\&&&\lambda_n}
$$
The statement follows.

---

Note: we have $w_1 = d^Tv_1$ since
$$
w_1 = e_1^*w = (U^*v_1)^*(U^*d) = v_1^* d = v_1^Td
$$

Comment: Why should $u_1$ be a norm $1$ eigenvector?